# How can i configure a background process which runs a python script in my django project at specified intervals of time

Tags: python, django

I am trying to create a django web application which will scan all the network devices in a network. As a part of this I am running my own python script to scan the network when user clicks on a scan button. Now I would like to run the script in background at user specified intervals of time.In what way I can do this. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Using `celery` with `django-celery`, you can easily add periodic tasks through the admin interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In simple cases use [cron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron):

```
# Run every workday at 22:00
0 22 * * 1-5 python manage.py command
```

Comment: This is fine if you only have one application server, and the intervals can fit nicely into a cron job. If you need more frequent than a cron job allows, or if you plan to scale to multiple application servers, then you should use celery.

Comment: Yep, it's super simple, but can **run script periodically in background**. So if you don't need control the process it's ok.

Comment: @Murad Byashimov, I should be able to edit those intervals according to user input from UI. is it possible with cron?

Comment: Nope. Then you should use Celery. It's pretty much cool tool.